# How safe is a direct JWT exchange?

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm planning on coding a app in react native that requires authorization. So i was thinkning about using JWT and i was wondering if the exchange for the user to get the JWT couldn't just be direct.

What I mean is, after the user sends his login to the serveur, the serveur just sends back the jwt with the users ID in it, and then the user just stocks it. Would that be unsafe ?

is that what discord does ?

its a theoric question

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately questions like this are off-topic for the forum, because they invite opinion-based answers.  The answer to "is this safe?" is almost always "Sure, unless..." because attack vectors are endless and best practices change.  The question might be on topic here (although I don't know the community, so check their guidelines): https://security.stackexchange.com